# How can we save the path of the uploaded image src in a file

Tags: javascript, image, web

I am trying to save the src of the image which was dynicmally upladed by me so whenever i logsout my site i've to again upload the image for the website logo pic

Comment: I'm not sure what actually you're asking, but this sounds like a task for the server-side ..?

Comment: actually i'm uploading a logo for my website dynamically that every user can change logo accordingly and the issue i'm facing write now is that the src of the image is not saving any where so i've to upload the picture on every single login

Comment: Do you want everyone to see their own logo, or should an arbitrarily uploaded logo be seen on every document?

Comment: yeah exactly all i want is that each user can upload their own logos and then the path or src of the uploaded pic or logo must be kept and saved inside

Comment: Upload with AJAX, and send the image path back as a response. Then use cookies or local storage to save the path for the browser, and create a JS to change the logo at onload.

Comment: thanks alot :) appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you are carry about the client side. So, you can use cookies instead.

```js
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value +
                    expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
  var cArr = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < cArr.length;i++) {
    var cookie = cArr[i].split("=",2);
    cookie[0] = cookie[0].replace(/^\s+/,"");
    if (cookie[0] == name){ return cookie; }
  }
}

setCookie("src", "c:\myimage.png", 10000);
var c1 = getCookie("src");
console.log(c1)
```